# How to get the parameter of http.send() for post method from the server side?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, oracle11g, httprequest

I want to develop a website where the database is in the server. When a user types something in a text field, suggestions will come from the database (which is in the server) on the fly. I have thought of a solution like this:

- The client will send the request of a database query as the parameter of `http.send()` `POST` method.
- The server will take this parameter and run a SQL query.
- The server will send the resultset as an ArrayList to the client.
- The browser in the client side will show suggestions based on this ArrayList.

My question is, how the server will the parameter of `http.send()`. As I am generating the suggestions on the fly, maybe I have to use it inside javascript in my JSP page.

Note: I am using Spring MVC framework along with Oracle 11g database.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities in Java on how you can achieve this. The answer you're probably looking for is something like [this](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-jquery-autocomplete-example/).

An other solution would be to use JSF components for example. Have a look at this [PrimeFaces autocomplete showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) and [MKYong's JSF tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/).

Comment: This example loads data from a link- not from a database. Also, here no request is sent from the client side to the server side.

Comment: The request is sent via an ajax call. In the first example, this is embedded in the jQuery UI's autocomplete. There's an example on the jQuery's [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp)

Comment: Also, the implementation of getting the data (in your case, the database)  is completely up to you.